# Modulus Notation Division

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I have a couple of silly questions (it will definitely demonstrate my lack of ability in mathematics :P)

Is there a type of reduction or absorption of modulus in congruence equations? Here's an example:

If I have 
$$x (mod 3) \equiv 22 (mod 3)$$, is that the same as finding $ x \equiv 22 mod 3$ or could I get rid of the modulus all together, making $x=22$? I'm trying to prove that the sum of all primitive roots mod $p$ is $\mu(p-1)$ mod $p$.

Secondly, any tips on how to prove the above theorem mentioned (with the sum of all primitive roots)? It took me a while to realize that I can write the sum of all primitive roots as $$\sum_{i=1}^k (a^{r_i})^m$$. I apologize if there's anything obvious I'm missing...I've never taken number theory, and weak in abstract algebra.

Comment: You can never get rid of a modulus.  If $x \equiv 22 \pmod 3$, that means that $x$ minus $22$ is divisible by $3$.  That means $x$ could be $22$...or $25, 19, 28, 16$ or lots of other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a problem in that mathematicians and computer-scientists use “mod” differently. Mathematician says “$-2\equiv13\pmod5$”, meaning that congruence modulo $5$ is an equivalence relation, $a\equiv b\pmod n$ means that $b-a$ is an integer multiple of $n$.

Computer scientist says, “$-2\bmod5=3$”, making “$\!\bmod n$” a function whose range is the set $\{0,1,\cdots,n-1\}$, the value being computed as the (nonnegative) remainder of the input upon Euclidean division by $n$. In this convention, we can say $-2\bmod5=13\bmod5$, because both times, the value of the expression is $3$.

For mathematicians, the computer-science convention is (almost) useless, because it doesn’t generalize to other systems than the integers, even in such a simple case as the Gaussian integers.